# Better design for a shunt resistor load on a voltage divider

Tags: circuit-design, current-measurement, shunt

A bit new to circuit design.
I'm designing a helper circuit that monitors incoming current. For testing purposes, we'll be taking inputs of max ~5 V and dropping this down to the millivolts, and pass it through a 100 µΩ shunt resistor. The current limit for this is about 75 A.

I feel like this approach is naive, and could be accomplished in a better way, but I do not have enough experience designing circuits to know what can be designed better.

My current design is attached as a schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu8usu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R2 is doing pretty much nothing.  Are you trying to measure the current through R1?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're doing here. Why do you have a 100 kΩ resistor in parallel with a 100 μΩ resistor?

Comment: @JRE, I'm trying to measure current through the shunt resistor. I'm new to this shunt resistor stuff, and was told that in order to scale down the input voltage we should be using a voltage divider. However, because the shunt resistor is in parallel with the second resistor of the divider it kind of messed with my calculations which I might have done incorrectly.

Comment: @Hearth I don't really know. I'm sorry that that is a very awful response but I was told by the person assigning this to me that a voltage divider would be best and that we should use common resistors for it. In simulating this, 100k got me a good accuracy for the current reading, but I honestly don't see how this circuit is supposed to work overall - regardless, all the current will be pushed through R1.

Comment: @Vortexian, take a step back and tell us what the original problem is. You want to measure "incoming current". 1. Incoming to what? 2. What is the expected measurement range? 3. With what will you measure the voltage across the shunt?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to "scale down the input voltage", when you're measuring current. Either the person assigning you this had something very different in mind, or they don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @Hearth, the shunt resistor we are using isn't rated to experience 5 volts across it, and for our application the maximum voltage across should be about 7mV. I did some more asking, and got better info about this whole thing. The voltage divider is for us to test the shunt resistor, but when fully installed the divider won't be connected to the shunt as I drew in the schematic - it will experience the full output from the system we are connecting it to. If we experience current > 70 amps across the shunt, we kill the system.

Comment: @Transistor, sorry, I should have specified better. 1. Incoming from a battery pack. 2. 0-70 amps, above which we kill the system receiving from the battery pack. 3. [This](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina186.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe) is connected to both ends of the shunt resistor.

Comment: There still seems to be some kind of disconnect here. It would make some small amount of sense to test a current shunt amplifier such as the INA186 by applying a small voltage to it. However, you can't do this with the shunt in place. Or rather, the only way to create a small voltage across a 100 uOhm shunt is to force a large current through the shunt (this is just Ohm's law). If you get rid of the 100 uOhm shunt in your circuit, you can adjust R1 and R2 to apply a small voltage to the current shunt amplifier (for example 7 mV if that is your goal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The [INA186 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina186.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe) makes it quite clear how the shunt, R<sub>SENSE</sub>, should be connected.*

Depending on which gain version you have chosen you select a shunt resistor that will give you the required input voltage across R<sub>SENSE</sub> at your rated current, 75 A.

Comment: Thank you. I was misreading and very caught up in my own thoughts on this. Both your messages and @mkeith's helped me with this - thank you.